# How to fix models to camera in a-frame?

Tags: javascript, html, aframe

I want to attach an object to camera, to be the object anywhere where camera looks, turns etc. I tried like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.8.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a-scene>
      <a-assets>
        <a-asset-item  id="gun"   position="0 -1 -5" rotation="90 360 0" scale="0 0 0"  src="gun.gltf"></a-asset-item>
      <a-entity camera="active: true" look-controls wasd-controls position="0 0 5" data-aframe-default-camera></a-entity>
      <a-entity camera look-controls>
        <a-entity gltf-model="#gun" position="0 -1 -5" rotation="0 90 35" scale="0.4 0.4 0.4" id="my_gun"></a-entity>
      </a-entity>
      <a-sky color="#ECECEC"></a-sky>
    </a-scene>
  </body>
</html>
```

But this remains constantly on `position="0 -1 -5"` and if I don't use position at this point then the camera is inside the object... How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Preventing camera from going 'through' aframe object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43461331/preventing-camera-from-going-through-aframe-object)

Comment: @FerasAlSous that question isn't about how to attach object to camera, is just about how to prevent to be the camera inside the object. I think, this is 2 different things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change

```
<a-entity camera="active: true" look-controls wasd-controls position="0 0 5" data-aframe-default-camera></a-entity>
      <a-entity camera look-controls>
        <a-entity gltf-model="#gun" position="0 -1 -5" rotation="0 90 35" scale="0.4 0.4 0.4" id="my_gun"></a-entity>
      </a-entity>
```

to

```
<a-entity camera="active: true" look-controls wasd-controls position="0 0 5" data-aframe-default-camera>
<a-entity gltf-model="#gun" position="0 -1 -5" rotation="0 90 35" scale="0.4 0.4 0.4" id="my_gun">
</a-entity>
</a-entity>
```

There was two different cameras, I think this was the problem.